# Is there a way to set a cookie during a test using PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, phpunit

I have a application that uses an external service via a cookie set to my applications domain. During development I create this cookie by hand but in production this cookie would be generated via a login. Is there any way to use the cookie I set during development before I run my tests for this external service?

I have a guess that I can use curl to automate this a little but I was wondering if I missing some hidden feature or technique in PHPUnit and/or Selenium.

[class extending **PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase**]

```
/**
 * Can get the current authenticated user.
 */
public function testCanGetTheCurrentAuthenticatedUser()
{
    $this->open('http://my/local/virtual/host/api/getCurrentUser');
    $json = json_decode($this->getBodyText());
    $this->assertEquals('25', $json->response->id); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Selenium documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html) has `createCookie()`, and it's listed as a method in `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`. From the docs you can use the following to set the `login` cookie to `frank.wilson` for five minutes.

```
$this->createCookie('login=frank.wilson', 'max_age=600');
```

Comment: The information is good but my problem is still not solved. David, do you have any example code using createCookie?

Comment: I haven't used it yet. Our Selenium-based testing is very limited. Try using `getCookie()` or `getCookieByName()` after `createCookie()` to see if it was set. Another option is to see if Selenium 2 works.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using Curl for tests that required cookie authentication.

```
$curl = curl_init('http://my/local/virtual/host/api/getCurrentUser');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'mycookie=authentication'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
$json = json_decode($output);
$this->assertEquals('25', $json->response->id);
```